# Rotate a matrix represented in a 1D vector by 90 degrees

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I want to rotate a matrix by 90 degrees in place represented in the form of a 1D vector.

When it is in 2D, this is what I did that works:

```
void rotate(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
    reverse(matrix.begin(), matrix.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i){
        for (int j= i + 1; j < matrix[0].size(); ++j) {
            swap(matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I represent it in 1D, for example:

```
vector<int> matrix = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

This is what I tried:

```
void rotate(vector<int>& matrix, const int& n) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            swap(matrix[i + j], matrix[i + j * n]);
        }
        reverse(matrix.begin() + i * n, matrix.begin() + (i * n) + j);
    }
}
```

The result was:

```
matrix = {7, 4, 1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 2, 3}
```

But the **expected** result should be:

```
matrix = {7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 6, 3}
```

Is there a better way to do this or what am I missing, in terms of indexing?

Comment: I have no idea what *rotate an matrix by 90 degrees* means. Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi Sahu, rotate by 90 degrees clockwise would give for matrix m = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], result [[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3]], now given m in 1D vector, I want to do the same in in place and result [7,4,1, 8,5,2, 9,6,3]. Thank you!

Comment: I guess what "rotate a matrix by 90 degrees" means here is "transpose a matrix"

Comment: Like you said, in terms of indexing something is wrong : simply do swap(matrix[i * n + j], matrix[i + j * n]) and remove the call to reverse ? also the bounds of the j iteration should be changed ans start at 'i'

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it.

At this line:

```
swap(matrix[i + j], matrix[i + j * n]);
```

Your first indexing should be `i * n + j`. That's basically the "formula" to convert 2D indices into 1D (for square matrices only). So, `matrix[i][j]` becomes `matrix[i * n + j]`. The same thing applies in reverse: `matrix[j][i]` becomes `matrix[j * n + i]`, just like you did originally on the second swap parameter.

Lastly, at this line:

```
reverse(matrix.begin()+i*n, matrix.begin() + (i*n)+ j);
```

The last expression should be `(i * n) + n`.

To explain this, you can walk through the code. Assuming we reached the second reverse, after the inner loop finished, and we're at the second iteration of the outer loop (`i = 1`). The array will look something like this before the reverse:

```
. . . 2 5 8 . . .
```

And we want to reverse this group to this:

```
. . . 8 5 2 . . .
```

Now in order to reverse just that middle part, we need to get the index range for these three numbers.

The start index would be `i * n` or `1 * 3 = 3` in this case and `(i * n) + n` (or `(i + 1) * n`) which would evaluate to `(1 * 3) + 3 = 6`, representing the end index correctly.